# you made me confused

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Generally we say "You made me confused". I've heard from somewhere that we use "confuse" if an object would be present there. I don't know when it happens; could you give me an example for that (usage of "confuse" other than "confused")?

Comment: Make sure you do not **confuse** a transitive verb that takes an object with an intransitive verb that does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pincesadh. I'm not sure I quite understand your question, but I will try to answer it as best I can.

Let us put the "make" to one side for a moment.

*Confuse* is a transitive verb, which normally requires the object to be explicit:

> That book confuses me.
>
> John is confusing me.
>
> I confused Mary.

It can go in the passive, and then has the form *confused* following a part of *be*:

> I am confused by that book.
>
> I am being confused by John. (I find this sentence barely acceptable, but I'm not sure why)
>
> Mary was confused by me.

You can also use *confused* as an adjective:

> I am confused.
>
> John was confused.

This is referring to a state, rather than a process. It is not always possible to distinguish the two senses of *confused*.

Now we bring in *make*. In this use, it is sometimes called a **causitive** verb - it expresses that somebody causes something. With a following verb, it expresses that somebody causes the action - and if the verb requires an object so will it in this causitive construction.

So

> I sleep. => It makes me sleep.

and

> I confuse Mary. -> John makes me confuse Mary.

It can also be used with an adjective, in which case it means something like "causes to be". So

> I am angry. -> John makes me angry.
>
> I am confused. -> John makes me confused.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: You have really helped me. I need to ask you a question related to your one example i.e "John make me confuse Mary" can I write "John makes me to confuse marry"?

Answer (score 0):

"Confuse" is transitive verb, which requires a direct object. In the sentence you suggest, you are using the past participle "confused" as an adjective, but otherwise you can say "You are confusing me," or "You have confused me," or "You confused me." In each case, "me" is the direct object. Also possible, "You confuse the situation with comments like that," "You are confusing one object for another," etc., in which "the situation" and "One object" are the direct objects of the verb.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following examples (object of "confuse" in bold):

- Don't confuse **the issue**.
- I often confuse **one thing** with another.
- She confuses **me** with her questions.

*Confuse* does take an object (i.e. it's a transitive verb), but the example sentence that you provided uses "confused" as a participle. You'll better understand why there is no object after "confused" in your example if you research how participles are used.